Determining Intermediate Swap Outputs in Multi-DEX Solana Transactions
When a user creates a transaction with multiple swap instructions across different DeFi protocols, how can they determine the output amount from the first swap if they don't explicitly specify it?

Typically, you would go through a program (like Jupiter) that reads out the new state of the token accounts in between swaps to use the correct amount
